# How is it valid to compare p-value vs alpha-value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

We know that a p-value can be interpreted as the probability of seeing the same response given that the null hypothesis is true.

p-value is not the probability of making a type 1 error. (as emphasized here: http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/how-to-correctly-interpret-p-values)

However, the significance level, alpha, we know corresponds to the probability type 1 error.

**How does it make sense to make comparison with alpha and p-value?** They represent to different probabilities.

Comment: Your opening sentence is wrong, or too sloppy for use here. Neither is it standard to equate "the significance level" with "alpha". Perhaps you should edit your question, but I suspect that it has been answered already several times before. Use the search function for P-values and alpha.

Comment: Welcome to CV unknown! While I agree with @MichaelLew regarding the definitions, I think you are quite welcome to ask this question here. After all, it is not *wrong* to be incorrect, and we learn by making mistakes. Hopefully I or someone else will provide an answer that helps clarify.

Comment: I found that definition online. I felt it was important to ensure that we were on the same page.

Comment: Yeah, my comment now looks more grumpy than I actually felt. Sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> a p-value can be interpreted as the probability of seeing the same response given that the null hypothesis is true.

Not quite: **the *p*-value is the probability of observing a test statistic that is *as or more extreme* than the one you actually observed.**  This is why the *p*-value is expressed as a probability in terms of an inequality: $p = P\left(\Theta \ge \theta\right)$, $p = P\left(\Theta \le \theta\right)$, or $p = P\left(|\Theta| \ge |\theta|\right)$.

> However, the significance level, alpha, we know corresponds to the probability type 1 error.

Almost: **$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is a *researcher choice*, and represents the willingness of the researcher to falsely reject a single null hypothesis, *assuming that the null hypothesis is true*.**

In the frequentist world it makes sense to reject test statistics that are too unlikely... *too extreme* assuming the null hypothesis is true. The reasoning is along the lines of "if this test statistic, $\theta$, was *so* unlikely to be observed if the null hypothesis is true, then perhaps the null hypothesis isn't true!" The *p*-value is the measure of "how extreme" under the null.

The value of $\alpha$ indicates the researcher's line in the sand: probabilities of observing test statistics as or more extreme as $\alpha$ (because they are smaller than $\alpha$) are rejected because *both probabilities are defined under the assumption that the null hypothesis—including the distribution implied by it—is true.*

Comment: Hmm, what does `extreme` mean? If I understand, the p-value is the probability that we'll see a response as powerful as we saw the sample data?

Comment: A more extreme test statistic value is a value of that statistic that can be expected to occur less commonly according to the relevant sampling distribution. In most cases a more extreme value of the test statistic has a larger absolute value, and corresponds to a dataset that can be thought of as more surprising according to the null hypothesis.

Comment: @unknown "More extreme" is right there in the $p = P(\Theta \ge \theta)$, $p = P(\Theta \le \theta)$, and $p = P(|\Theta| \ge |\theta|)$. Notice that none of those expressions are $p = P(\Theta =\theta)$: the inequality ($\ge$ or $\le$) means *as or more* extreme.

Comment: @MichaelLew +1 for the "in most cases." :)